# How to make a time to value function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function where it selects a time and converts the time in mins into a value. Here is my code and im getting a typerror in my console log.

Please see this fiddle to see the error i am getting
https://jsfiddle.net/tjhunt03/npLxq0hm/16/

[image]

```js
function _slicedToArray(arr, i) {
  return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest();
}

function _nonIterableRest() {
  throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance");
}

function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) {
  var _arr = [];
  var _n = true;
  var _d = false;
  var _e = undefined;
  try {
    for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) {
      _arr.push(_s.value);
      if (i && _arr.length === i) break;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    _d = true;
    _e = err;
  } finally {
    try {
      if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"]();
    } finally {
      if (_d) throw _e;
    }
  }
  return _arr;
}

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr;
}


var mealBreakStringToValue = function mealBreakStringToValue(timeStr) {
  var _timeStr$match = timeStr.match(/(\d+):(\d+) ([ap]m)/),
    _timeStr$match2 = _slicedToArray(_timeStr$match, 4),
    hours = _timeStr$match2[1],
    minutes = _timeStr$match2[2],
    ampm = _timeStr$match2[3];

  var minutesModifier = minutes === 'mins' ? 15 : 30;
  return Number(hours) + ampmHourModifier + minutes / 60;
};
console.log(mealBreakStringToValue('30 mins'));
```

Comment: It would help if you format your code. The easier it is to read, the more likely people are to read it (and maybe provide answers). :-)

Comment: Your regex is not matching the input '30 mins'

Comment: On a sidenote: you should read up on scopes and pure functions.

Comment: @Boney could you please show me how to do this?

Comment: `converts the time in mins into a value`. what do you mean by "value" here? Also what is the expected format of the input ? It will be good if you can show an example with the expected input and output.

Comment: So with the drop down select I have given a start and finish time a certain value (eg 7am would relate to 7) which is working atm as My regex matches to am/pm. but not so sure how to match it with minutes with 'mins' as its input value. I have included a screenshot for you where my code is as an example.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the comments, you need to convert the string '30 mins' to the equivalent number of hours. Below is the code that does that. You need to have a different regex than the one you have used for parsing 'am/pm' string.

```js
var mealBreakStringToValue = function mealBreakStringToValue(mealBreak) {
  const mealBreakMatch = mealBreak.match(/(\d{1,2}) mins/i);
  const minutes = mealBreakMatch[1];
  return Number(minutes / 60);
};
console.log(mealBreakStringToValue('30 mins'));
```

Comment: Yep, exactly it, you explained it perfectly, sorry I couldn't word it properly!

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer in case the issue is resolved.